# Length of string separated by spaces

Tags: command-line, bash

I have this variable in an Ubuntu bash script and I am looking to extract its length:

```
var_names='test1 tutorial2 test3w'
```

In a Python list, I could do `len(var_names)` and the result would be 3. I need to do something similar in a bash script - **I need to find a way to determine the length of the string and for the answer to be 3**.

My attempt:

I tried to convert this into an array an then test its length:

```
arr=($var_names)
echo ${#arr[@]}
```

however:

```
echo $arr
```

only gives

```
test1
```

Question:

Howe do I get the length of this variable in bash, such that the returned length is 3?

Comment: I'm confused - is the output of `echo ${#arr[@]}` **not** `3`? if not, what is it? what is the relevance of the value of `$arr` (which is equivalent to `${arr[0]}`, I think - i.e. it *should* be the first element of the array)

Comment: My thought with that approach was to convert it to an array and then determine its length. I didn't try `echo ${#arr[@]}` yet. I get `$arr` which only gave 1 element and left out the other 2. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: If you want to get the *whole* array, you can use `"${arr[@]}"`; if you want the lengths of the individual element strings, `${#arr[0]}`, `${#arr[1]}`, and `${#arr[2]}`

Comment: @steeldriver Add an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct,`${#arr[@]}` will give you the number of elements in the array (in this case, 3):

```
$ var_names='test1 tutorial2 test3w'
$ arr=($var_names)
$ echo ${#arr[@]}
3
```

You can also return the string lengths of the individual array elements using `${#arr[0]}`, `${#arr[1]}` and so on:

```
$ echo "${#arr[0]}"
5
$ echo "${#arr[1]}"
9
$ echo "${#arr[2]}"
6
```

The reason that `$arr` returns only the first element `test1` is that it is equivalent to `${arr[0]}`; if you want to return the whole array, you can use either `${arr[@]}` or `${arr[*]}`:

```
echo "${arr[@]}"
test1 tutorial2 test3w
```

See the `Arrays` section of `man bash`

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are effectively trying to find number of words in the variable, you can use `wc -w` command for that:

```
$ var_names='test1 tutorial2 test3w'                                                                                     

$ wc -w <<< "$var_names" 
3
```